# Script works only one time

Tags: lua, roblox

**Summarize the problem**
I have a script that is in the server storage.
When a block is clicked, the script gets cloned and assigned as child to the block to make the script start. At the end of the script it gets destroyed but rest in the storage.
It works perfectly the first time it gets cloned and then destroyed. But when I click the block again to make the script clone and work, it gives me problems. It gets cloned but it doesn't start.

**Describe what you’ve tried**
I've tried searching around for someone with my same problem, sadly i couldn't find it.

**When appropriate, show some code**

**part of the code that clone the script**

> The ClickDetector is located in the workspace

```
local Touch = game.ServerStorage.TakeToTable:Clone()
Touch.Parent = ClickDetector
```

**code that doesn't start the second time**

```
local ClickDetect = script.Parent
local Clients = {ClickDetect:FindFirstChild('Client1'), ClickDetect:FindFirstChild('Client2'), ClickDetect:FindFirstChild('Client3'),
    ClickDetect:FindFirstChild('Client4')}
    
local Tables = {
    game.Workspace.Tables.Table1, game.Workspace.Tables.Table2,game.Workspace.Tables.Table3,game.Workspace.Tables.Table4,
    game.Workspace.Tables.Table5,game.Workspace.Tables.Table6,game.Workspace.Tables.Table7,game.Workspace.Tables.Table8,
    game.Workspace.Tables.Table9,game.Workspace.Tables.Table10,game.Workspace.Tables.Table11,game.Workspace.Tables.Table12,
    game.Workspace.Tables.Table13,game.Workspace.Tables.Table14,game.Workspace.Tables.Table15,game.Workspace.Tables.Table16,
    game.Workspace.Tables.Table17,game.Workspace.Tables.Table18,game.Workspace.Tables.Table19}

ClickDetect.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    for index = 1,#Tables do
        local ClickDetectTables = Instance.new('ClickDetector')
        ClickDetectTables.Parent = Tables[index]
    end
    for index = 1,#Tables do
        Tables[index].ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
            if #Clients == 1 or #Clients == 2 then
                local LetsGo = game.ServerStorage.LetsWalk:Clone()
                LetsGo.Parent = script.Parent
                local Table = Instance.new('Frame')
                Table.Parent = ClickDetect.TakeToTable
                Table.Name = "Table" .. index
                for index = 1, #Tables do
                    Tables[index].ClickDetector:Destroy()
                end
                local PathToTable = Tables[index].Path:Clone()
                PathToTable.Parent = script.Parent
                PathToTable.Name = "PathToTable"
            end
            
            if #Clients == 3 or #Clients == 4 then
            local Seats = {Tables[index]:FindFirstChild('Seat1'), Tables[index]:FindFirstChild('Seat2'),
                Tables[index]:FindFirstChild('Seat3'),
                Tables[index]:FindFirstChild('Seat4')}
                if #Seats == 3 or #Seats == 4 then
                    local LetsGo = game.ServerStorage.LetsWalk:Clone()
                    LetsGo.Parent = script.Parent
                    local Table = Instance.new('Frame')
                    Table.Parent = ClickDetect.TakeToTable
                    Table.Name = "Table" .. index
                    for index = 1, #Tables do
                        Tables[index].ClickDetector:Destroy()
                    end
                    local PathToTable = Tables[index].Path:Clone()
                    PathToTable.Parent = script.Parent
                    PathToTable.Name = "PathToTable"
                end
            end 
            end)
    end
    
end)
```

Comment: Heyo, you should always share your code with the minimal amount to help us understand what you're doing. And when describing the problem, could you be a little more specific than just saying that it doesn't work? Is the Script starting at all? Are errors showing up in the Output widget?

Comment: @Kylaaa 
The code doesn't start at all, no errors. It's like it always stays in the server storage, even tho I changed the parent

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code that clones and moves the script. Where did you change the parent to? Scripts only execute in the Workspace and ServerScriptService. Also, are the Scripts Disabled?

Comment: @Kylaaa imma add the script right away

Comment: @Kylaaa added the codes. The scripts aren't disabled and they get moved to the workspace right away after getting cloned.

Comment: In the first code block, where is `ClickDetector` defined? Right now, it looks like it is nil. Are you sure the script is making it into the Workspace?

Comment: @Kylaaa the clickdetector position is in the workspace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248044/discussion-between-karma-idk-and-kylaaa).

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely that `ClickDetector` is an undefined value in your first code block.

Because you don't have a line that locates the ClickDetector in the Workspace, the `ClickDetector` variable evaluates as `nil`. And when you set the Parent property to nil, it removes it from the game.

So the fix is simple, just define the variable with the path to the object. (I'm assuming the object is named ClickDetector)

```lua
-- find the detector in the Workspace...
local ClickDetector = game.Workspace.ClickDetector

-- clone the script to the detector...
local Touch = game.ServerStorage.TakeToTable:Clone()
Touch.Parent = ClickDetector
```